# Replace any string before "/", PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace any string before "/", irrespective of the string length.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: you should show an example of what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one way, assuming you want to change the string before the first "/".

```
$str = "anystring/the_rest/blah";
$s = explode("/",$str);
$s[0]="new string";
print_r ( implode("/",$s) );
```

Comment: You, know the funny thing is I tried that stuff out, I got my head scratching, stopped short of my balls, then stacked overflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
echo preg_replace('/^[^\/]+/', 'baz', 'foo/bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be the most efficient, although i still prefer the preg_replace() technique

```
$pos = strpos($input, '/');
if ($pos >= 0) {
    $output = $replacement . substr($input, $pos);
} else {
    $output = $input;
}
```