# Replace first part of string with db string

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace, slash

Could u help me with code ?
I want to add t that script an option like :
when I type ex. data/pag , then script replaces data with key from mysql db and echo it like:  replaced/pag . I mean it only replaces text before first and single "/".

Code :

```
 $wyszukaj=$_GET['wyszukaj'];

 $min_wartosc = 1;

 if(strlen($wyszukaj)>=$min_wartosc)
 {
     $wyszukaj =htmlspecialchars($wyszukaj);

     $zapytanie=$baza->prepare("SELECT * FROM wyszukiwarka WHERE nazwa LIKE :wyszukaj");

     $zapytanie->bindValue('wyszukaj', $_GET['wyszukaj'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $zapytanie->execute(array($wyszukaj));

     if($zapytanie->rowCount()>0)
     {
          while($wynik=$zapytanie->fetch())
         {
             echo $wynik['nazwa'] . "<br>";
              header('location:http://'.$wynik['login']);
         }
      }
           else
         {
              echo "brak <b> " . $wyszukaj . " </b> w bazie danych ...";
          }
     }
     else
     {
          echo "";
     }
```

Comment: your question is about a replacement of text in a string of text (containing a /). Then there is a lot of code, but where is the part the question is about?

Comment: I mean , I can't do this . Asking for help. I know that I have to add elseif but I don't know in which part and how to construct it.

Comment: Do you mean you will send wyszukaj=data/page to your php?  You want data to be 'replaced' with something from the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace any string before "/", PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279288/replace-any-string-before-php)

Comment: Yep , I mean when I type to input text :    "sometext/second"   then script  checks if there is sometext in db , and then replace id  so prints : replaced/second as echo , when not id db then just other echo*. It must check text only for first "/" , It other echo* when  it has sometext/sometext/second.